# WPF MenuItem Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I faced an issue regarding MenuItem Binding, I need to bind a nested object to a `MenuItem`.

```
public class QuestionType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<QuestionType> Types { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ICollection<QuestionType> QuestionTypes { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        QuestionTypes = new List<QuestionType>()
        {
            new QuestionType() { Name="Completion" },
            new QuestionType() { Name="Easy" },
            new QuestionType() { Name="MoreType", Types = new List<QuestionType>()
            {
                new QuestionType() { Name="SingleChoice" },
                new QuestionType() { Name="MultiChoice" },
                new QuestionType() { Name="Blend" },
            } },
        };
    }
}

public partial class CustomMenu : UserControl
{
    public CustomMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

In XAML Code:

I binding them to MenuItem like this way:

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionTypes}">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:QuestionType}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Types}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:QuestionType}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
</MenuItem>
```

When I run my project, an exception occurred.
Additional information: `Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.`

In addition:
I need to add click event for Menu Item like

```
<MenuItem.Resources>
 ...
</MenuItem.Resources>
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="Menu.Click" Handler="MenuItem_Click"/>
    </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

It didn't work, I don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Question Type" ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionTypes}" Click="MenuItem_Click">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:QuestionType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Types}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
</MenuItem>
```